# Dart: List in Map: The return type 'void' isn't a 'List<OverlapParams>', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Map with:

```
Map<int,List<OverlapParams>> map = new Map<int,List<OverlapParams>>();
```

And I want to upsert elements to the Map, so like, when Map key 2 is not existing, I want to save a `List<OverlapParams>` there. - if the Map key is exisiting, I want to add the item `overlapitem` to the List in the map.

Here is my code:

```
  final overlapitem = OverlapParams(childParentData.hashCode.toString(), DateTimeRange(
    start: childParentData.startDateTime ?? DateTime(2000),
    end: childParentData.endDateTime ?? DateTime(2000),
  ), {});
  int pos = childParentData.position ?? 0;

  map.update(
    pos,
    (existingValue) => (existingValue as List<OverlapParams>).add(overlapitem),
    ifAbsent: () => [overlapitem],
  );
```

but I get folowing error with underlined `(existingValue as List<OverlapParams>).add(overlapitem)`:

```
error: The return type 'void' isn't a 'List<OverlapParams>', as required by the closure's context.
```

I dont understand what void means in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the `update` method is `V update(V value)`.

What does that mean in English? A method that receives a parameter of type V *and returns an instance of type V*.

Now lets look at what you passed as parameter:

```
(existingValue) => (existingValue as List<OverlapParams>).add(overlapitem),
```

Now, it clearly is a method. It clearly get a parameter. What does it return? Nothing on the first glance. On second look, since you have no explicit return, it returns the result of the expression `(existingValue as List<OverlapParams>).add(overlapitem)`. The result is `void`, since that is what `add` returns.

So that is why your compiler is complaining: your function is not returning what it is supposed to return.

You can *explicitly* return something:

```
(existingValue) => { 
  (existingValue as List<OverlapParams>).add(overlapitem); 
  return existingValue; 
}
```

If for some reason you want a *new* list to replace the old one (that is what the update method is meant for), you could return a new list from your anonymous function:

```
(existingValue) => [overlapitem,...existingValue],
```

I have removed the `as` part, this should not be neccessary, since your `V` type is already defined to be `List<OverlapParams>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value in the map.update function.
List.add(value) does not return anything

try this

```
map.update(
pos,
(existingValue)  {
  (existingValue as List<OverlapParams>).add(overlapitem);
  return existingValue;
},
ifAbsent: () => [overlapitem],
);
```

I haven't tested this out, but if existing value is immutable, then try this

```
map.update(
pos,
(existingValue)  {
  var oldList = (existingValue as List<OverlapParams>);
  oldList.add(overlapitem);
  return oldList;
},
ifAbsent: () => [overlapitem],
);
```

Comment: Your second version does not actually create a new list. If "add" would fail on the original, it would fail on yours, too.

Comment: You are right, I couldn't test it. But the gist remains the same. a value is expected